# Import content between Twig files

Tags: php, symfony, import, twig

How can I have a Twig file which imports some of it's content from a second Twig file in the same or a sub directory?

I am developing a project where multiple Twig files have content in common and I'm trying to avoid copying and pasting content between Twig files.

So, I want to have a subdirectory containing the shared markup and simply "import" into the relevant sections of the main Twig files.

With **import.list.html.twig** in the same directory as the main Twig file, I tried the following:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}StockBundle:StockController:index{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome to the StockController:List page</h1>

{% for stock in stocks %}
    <div class='list'>
        <div class='each stock'>
            <span class='name'>{{ stock.name }}</span>
            <span class='desc'>{{ stock.description }}</span>
            <span class='balc'>{{ stock.balance }}</span>
            <span class='edit'>
                <a href="{{ path('stock_edit', {'id':stock.id}) }}">edit</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% include 'import.list.html.twig' %}

{% endblock %}
```

... but I got the following error:

```
Unable to find template "import.list.html.twig" in ::base.html.twig at line 10.
```

Comment: Hi @sisko, just wondering if my answer worked for you, or if you figured this issue out?

Comment: Hi @JasonRoman. Indeed it did. My apologies, I meant to read again and mark you correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `include` it needs to know the namespace of where it is located.  When you do `::`, as in `{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}`, it comes from the `app/Resources/views` directory of your application.

See: [Template Naming and Locations Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-locations)

If your `import.list.html.twig` is in a bundle, you'll have to define that properly.  For instance, if you have **StockBundle** and a **Resources/views** directory in that bundle with its own `base.html.twig` template, you would have

```
{% include 'StockBundle::base.html.twig' %}
```

If you had, say, a **Stock** folder inside that bundle (attached to your StockController) and an `import.list.html.twig` template, you would have

```
{% include 'StockBundle:Stock:import.list.html.twig' %}
```

Note via [Registered Namespaced Twig Paths](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html) that you can also use a namespaced path instead.  They're actually faster as well.  So the above would instead be

```
{% include '@Stock/base.html.twig' %}
{% include '@Stock/Stock/import.list.html.twig' %}
```

Here's another good reference for [Symfony template best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations)

### NOTE

Since Symfony 2.2, you can use the `include()` [function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html), and this is the preferred way to include templates:

```
{{ include('@Stock/base.html.twig') }}
{{ include('@Stock/Stock/import.list.html.twig') }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 {% include 'StockBundle:Stock:import.list.html.twig' %}
```

instead of:

```
 {% include 'import.list.html.twig' %}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-templates